# Add value to a Mono<Entity> with Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, mapping, spring-webflux

I need to copy the property `Friends` (which is an ArrayList) from a `Mono<PersonEntity>` to a `Mono<UserEntity>` (which has not `Friends` property in the database), but I don't find the correct way to do it, so when i map the `Mono<UserEntity>` to Dto, the field `Friends` result to be an empty array [].

```
public Mono<Dto> findEntityByIdAndLabel(Long id, String label) {
    return getPersonByIdAndLabel(id, label).flatMap(person -> {
         return UserRepository.findByID(id);     
    })
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new EntityNotFoundException(entity.toString(), id.toString(), label)))
            .map(this::mapper);
}
```

I think I should add something after `findById(id)` but everything i tried until now didn't work.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't show `PersonEntity` and `UserEntity` we can only guess their properties and getter and setter methods. Still, something along the following lines should work:

```java
public Mono<Dto> findEntityByIdAndLabel(Long id, String label) {
    return getPersonByIdAndLabel(id, label)
        .zipWith(UserRepository.findByID(id))
        .map(tuple -> {
            List friends = tuple.getT1().getFriends();
            UserEntity user = tuple.getT2():
            user.setFriends(friends);
            return user;
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new EntityNotFoundException(entity.toString(), id.toString(), label)))
        .map(this::mapper);
}
```

The important thing is `zipWith`, which combines the result from a `Mono` and another `Mono` into a `Tuple2` that you can then easily map. You can read more about this in the [reference documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWith-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-).

Comment: Thank you, it worked with your solution and some adjustment to the Dto